# joomla module, where to put css?

Tags: joomla, joomla-module

I've just written joomla module. This is basic but working version of my moule. 
I want to 'effectize' it, so i need to work with some css. Elements of my module has own classes so i can style it very easy. But where to put CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically just create a css folder under my module's directory.  You can then use this call to include your css from your module's php code:
[JDocument::addStyleSheet](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/Document/JDocument.html#addStyleSheet)

Comment: Thanks.
but i decided to put css in <style></style>
It's simple enough for my module

Answer (score 0):

Yes but would still recommend to put CSS in a seperate folder as suggested by Will Mavis as it is the right professional approach.

Comment: It's 'more right', but it's still not very 'professional' to be delivering many different stylesheets with each page request. Ideally, these would be combined by joomla and delivered as a single file - maybe that happens in the latest version, but certainly not in 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

The assets for your Joomla extension should be put in the /media folder.

Eg:

For a module called mod_supermodule, put the files in:

```
/media/mod_supermodule/css
/media/mod_supermodule/images
/media/mod_supermodule/js
```